# Is there value to questions with a temporal context sensitivity?

Tags: discussion

This is mostly for my own curiosity. I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284966/is-menu-working-with-recent-firefox-or-chrome-browsers#35284966) pop up. It occurs to me that this question fits a couple categories that I'm never sure if they have value:

1. RTM - Check out caniuse or whatever appropriate docs, and the answer is going to be there (in this case, the answer happens to be a resounding no, it's not supported hardly at all)
2. It's asking specifically about the current (as of mid-february 2016) support of the feature. Is there any value in questions like these as they become outdated? Should it just be edited to be more along the lines of "What versions of common browsers support `<menu>`" / "At what point did `<menu>` gain support amongst common browsers?"

Not to say that anything really should be done with this question in particular, it just struck me as a good opportunity to ask since I see these types occasionally and i'm not sure how they fit in here. I assume this has probably been talked to death at some point, and it must be appropriate as I suspect that Basile has some experience with SO ettiquette/etc. with 112k rep. I just wasn't sure how to go about searching.

Forgive the title, I just can't seem to figure out how to phrase this one!

Comment: I'd call that off-topic as looking for an off-site resource myself... And even high rep users aren't immune from asking bad questions. Opinions may differ though.

Comment: I deleted my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Should it just be edited to be more along the lines of "What versions of common browsers support " / "At what point did  gain support amongst common browsers?"

No, I don't think so. I'm pretty sure that's not what he is asking.

In fact, I'd say the same thing you do here about the original question: forgive the title. What he's actually asking is *why* this isn't working in the browsers as described in the documentation. Secondarily, he's asking for a workaround (i.e., how to make his code work properly).

Neither of those questions are problematic for the enumerated reasons, nor do they generally run afoul of our guidelines.

Perhaps it would be better if the title of the question were tweaked slightly to *"Why isn't <menu> working on recent Firefox or Chrome browsers?"*

> 1. RTM - Check out caniuse or whatever appropriate docs, and the answer is going to be there (in this case, the answer happens to be a resounding no, it's not supported hardly at all)

Wait… That comment makes me wonder if you actually read Basile's question. One of us isn't understanding it. The way I read it, he is saying that the *behavior* he's observing is *inconsistent* with the documentation. Granted, the feature is described as "experimental", but then again, the examples given in the documentation are not working as the documentation suggests that they should. So this is not just a RTFM question. He read the manual, he's asking for clarification. That's *always* allowed.

> 2. It's asking specifically about the current (as of mid-february 2016) support of the feature. Is there any value in questions like these as they become outdated?

I feel you on this one, but I also want to emphasize caution. This is a dangerous line of thinking. If you follow it to its natural conclusion, we wouldn't be able to ask questions about the current version of *anything*, because it's just going to be obsolete soon. We couldn't ask about bugs or unexpected behavior in Roslyn because they're just going to be fixed in the next version. We couldn't ask about C++11 because it's obsoleted by C++14. We couldn't ask about how to back-port an application to Windows XP because it is "outdated". Et cetera.

There has to be some type of criteria for "will this question ever be useful to another human being in the future", which is why "debug this giant block of spaghetti code" questions are as wrong as they feel, but just because something is temporally localized doesn't mean it's a bad question.

Comment: I upvoted this (but deleted my original question).

Comment: It's entirely possible I did misunderstand. I'm not sure if there were any edits since I'm under 10k. When I read it, I didn't actually see a question statement. Either way, it wasn't really about that question in particular. Thanks for your thoughts, makes sense to me!

Comment: There was an edit, it added 2-3 lines at the bottom providing more detail about the code setup he currently has. The edits didn't change the heart of the question. But I understand you were trying to ask something more general, it is something that I remember coming up before, but it's been a very long time ago.